# Export dictionary to a JSON, sorted by keys

Tags: c#, .net, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

(the values are either string, int or double).
I export the dictionary to a JSON file:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDict);
```

I want the saved JSON to be sorted by keys.

Comment: Is this possibly an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Why do you need the file to be sorted ? You can sort whenever u deserialize it's contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use a [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2), it'll be serialized in order of the keys:

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<string, int>
{
    { "Z", 3 },
    { "B", 2 },
    { "A", 1 },
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{"A":1,"B":2,"Z":3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SortedDictionary`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2

It sorts your entries by key so you don't need to perform any sorting on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Just use temporary SortedDictionary object:

```
var unsortedDic = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"Z", 3},
    {"B", 2},
    {"A", 1},
};

var sortedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SortedDictionary<string, int>(unsortedDic));
```

Output:

```
{"A":1,"B":2,"Z":3}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can sort your dictionary like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDict.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the result will be sorted. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` makes no guarantees about retaining insertion order.